# Computing the accrued interest in trinomial tree

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm currently trying to compute the accrued interest in a trinomial Hull-White tree.

The setup is a bond with a facevalue of 100 that matures in 6 years with a coupon of 5% (annually compounding).

The tree has 10 time steps, meaning that dt = 0.6.
For each node time, i.e. 0,0.6,1.2,1.6 etc. I made a loop, that asks if the node-time has reached a coupon date, i.e. 0,1,2,3.. etc.

If a coupon is reached (e.g the coupon date 1 is reached at node-time 1.2 and 1.6) the accrued should be (1.2-1)*5=1 and (1.6-1)*5=4 respectively. I want to end up with a accrued at each node from 0 to 9 of [0,3,1,4,2,0,3,1,4,2]

But what i get now is [0,3,1,9,2,0,3,1,24,2].

My code is:

´´´

```
timesteps = 10
maturity = 6
coupon_dates = np.full(maturity+1, range(maturity+1))
dt = maturity/timesteps
node_times = [i * dt for i in range(timesteps)]
accrued = np.zeros(timesteps)

  for i in range(len(node_times)):
        accrued[i] = round(node_times[i] * 5)
        for j in range(len(coupon_dates)):
            if (node_times[i]-dt < coupon_dates[j] and node_times[i] >= coupon_dates[j]):
                accrued[i] = round((node_times[i] - coupon_dates[j]) * 5)
```

´´´

Can anyone help me with this problem? And do someone have a more efficient way to compute the accrued?


Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would start with a simple example that you can compute by hand, then create a table of values for accrued within each loop and write out the value you compute manually (you compute `accrued[i]` twice so make two columns for each in your table), then add print statements and write the actual value your code computes. Having a table of expected vs. actual will probably be enough to pinpoint exactly which iteration is having an issue. Perhaps it's something like float rounding error, but it's not easy to see without debugging a test case.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself.

´´´

```
    coupon_dates = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
    timesteps = 10
    accrued = []
    dt = 6/10
    coupon = 0.05
    face_value = 100
    for t in range(timesteps):
        coupon_date = max(i for i in coupon_dates if i <= t * dt)
        accrued.append((t * dt - coupon_date) * coupon * 100)
```

´´´

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).